# Issues using FuelUX with Foundation

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, zurb-foundation, fuelux

I have a project built on top of Zurb Foundation, now I need to use some FuelUX components such as "wizard" and "tree". For that I include Twitter Bootstrap library (2.3.2 version downloaded from Bootstrap site) and also include "all.min.js" from FuelUX, when I use the same HTML markup as come in `index.html` but for some reason it doesn't work. So I tried to fire the plugin using `$("#MyWizard").wizard()` and get this error:

> TypeError: $(...).wizard is not a function
>     $("MyWizard").wizard();

Any ideas in how to get this work?

**How I include scripts**

This is the order in which I include scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bundles/product/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js?0.1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bundles/product/js/fuelux/all.min.js?0.1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bundles/stock/js/jquery-impromptu.js?0.1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bundles/product/js/product.js?0.1"></script>
<script>
    $("MyWizard").wizard();
</script>
```

Comment: The FuelUX script has not been included correctly as it has not been loaded. Or possibly you have the scripts included in the wrong order. Please post the HTML where you include the `<script>` tags

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I edited my question to answer your doubt, please take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was also posted to https://github.com/ExactTarget/fuelux/issues/259 and from what I'm seeing, being careful to follow the instructions at https://github.com/ExactTarget/fuelux/wiki/Using-Fuel-UX#simple-integration-into-a-page should straighten things out.  Hope this helps!